# How do you write a Teradata SQL Statement with EITHER OR between two columns with multiple WHERE statements?

Tags: sql, case, teradata

I am trying to use two columns. DATA_IND gives values of "yes" or "no" and another column VIDEO_IND gives  "yes" or "no".

I want my query to return if either column has a "yes".

Return CASE (yes, yes)(yes,no)(no,yes) DO NOT return if (no,no)

```
SELECT 
    t.email,
    a.acct_sk,
    a.snapshot_dt,
    a.ACCT_SK,
    a.ACCT_ESTBD_DT,
    a.ACCT_TERM_DT, 
    a.CUST_EMAIL_ADDR,
    a.VOICE_IND, 
    a.DSL_IND, 
    a.FIOS_IND,
    a.DATA_IND,
    a.VIDEO_IND,
    e.acct_sk,
    e.BILL_DT,
    e.CURR_BILL_AMT

FROM Table 1 t

LEFT JOIN Table 2 a 
   ON t.email = a.CUST_EMAIL_ADDR 

LEFT JOIN Table 3 e
   ON a.acct_sk = e.acct_sk

WHERE t.email not in ('askforemail@dsjkahk.vv') 
   AND a.ACCT_TYPE_CD ='B'
   AND a.ACCT_ESTBD_DT between date '2019-09-01' and date '2019-09-30'
   AND a.snapshot_dt = DATE '2020-01-01'
   AND e.BILL_DT between date '2020-01-01' and date '2020-01-31';
```

Either of these two columns can be "yes", both can't be "No"
    a.DATA_IND,
    a.VIDEO_IND,

Answer (score 1):

How about adding this to the `where` clause:

```
and not (date_ind = 'no' and video_ind = 'no')
```

Or, assuming that the values are binary:

```
 and (data_ind = 'yes' or video_ind = 'yes')
```

Comment: EXCELLENT! I didn't realize I could use parenthesis like that!! Thank you so much!!